# Border image on ul tag html

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded an image of an empty frame

[image]

I wanted to use this frame to enclose a list of business hours

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6">
<div class="content4">
<ul class="grid cs-style" >
<li>
<figure>
<figcaption>
<div class="time-table">
<h3><span class="icon icons-ornament-left"></span> <span class="light">OPENING</span> TIME <span class="icon icons-ornament-right"></span></h3>
                <div class="inner-bg  js--timetable">
                <dl class="week-day" data-day="1">
                <dt>Monday</dt>
                <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="week-day light-bg" data-day="2">
                <dt>Tuesday</dt>
                <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="week-day" data-day="3">
                <dt>Wednesday</dt>
                <dd>8:00-18:00</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="week-day light-bg" data-day="4">
                <dt>Thursday</dt>
                <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="week-day" data-day="5">
                <dt>Friday</dt>
                <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="week-day light-bg" data-day="6">
                <dt>Saturday</dt>
                <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="week-day closed" data-day="0">
                <dt>Sunday</dt>
                <dd>CLOSED</dd>
                </dl>
                </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
                </div>
```

But i don't know how to put the image frame over or around the tag. And also how to resize the frame using CSS or HTML attributes to fit exactly around the list.Someone please assist.

Comment: `border-image` is what you are after.

Comment: use this image as your background image - navigate here to learn how to apply this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: use background-image and contain . maybe

Comment: curiously the image file is not entirely square, the vertical stripes expand outwards as you scroll down (try it on Paulie_Ds answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-image`

[**Border-image @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)

Something like this:

```css
.time-table {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border:60px solid transparent;
  border-image:url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dc6/e6E/dc6e6E8oi.png) 80 60 60 stretch;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6"><div class="time-table">
  <h3><span class="icon icons-ornament-left"></span> <span class="light">OPENING</span> TIME <span class="icon icons-ornament-right"></span></h3>
  <div class="inner-bg  js--timetable">
    <dl class="week-day" data-day="1">
      <dt>Monday</dt>
      <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="week-day light-bg" data-day="2">
      <dt>Tuesday</dt>
      <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="week-day" data-day="3">
      <dt>Wednesday</dt>
      <dd>8:00-18:00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="week-day light-bg" data-day="4">
      <dt>Thursday</dt>
      <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="week-day" data-day="5">
      <dt>Friday</dt>
      <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="week-day light-bg" data-day="6">
      <dt>Saturday</dt>
      <dd>9:00-18:00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="week-day closed" data-day="0">
      <dt>Sunday</dt>
      <dd>CLOSED</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This just looks perfect ...+1

Comment: You may have to play with some of the values depending on your final HTML, but the basics are there.